# Android emulator browser and application inconsistent hostname resolution

Tags: android, dns, android-emulator, hostname

I have an Android emulator running on my host machine (192.168.2.11) and a DNS server (bind) running on my DNS server (192.168.2.12). The DNS server has an entry for my internal hosted application and the Android emulator is invoked with the following command,

```
emulator @myemulator -scale 0.50 -dns-server 192.168.2.12
```

From the Android browser if I navigate to myinternal.domain.com, it is able to resolve the domain and the application loads. However, when the HTTP request is made through the application, the hostname resolution fails.

I have even tried by modifying the /etc/hosts file of the emulator but with no luck,

```
192.168.2.13    myinternal.domain.com
#10.0.2.2       myinternal.domain.com
```

My requirement is to use hostname than the IP address (default website) so I cannot modify the code to send HTTP requests to the IP address.

Is it possible that the Android browser and the application resolves hostname in a different way? Appreciate if someone can help me out to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my problem. This inconsistent behaviour was due to the installed version of Java (Oracle Java in my case). Replacing it with the Open-JDK version 1.7.80 solved the problem.

Thought to post this in-case if someone else is facing this issue and doesn't want to waste n hours on this :)